# How to correctly use getStaticProps for firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am very new to Next.js and could not get the `getStaticProps` to work correctly.

```
import firebase from '../firebase'

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All Posts</h1>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.pid}>{post.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  let posts = []
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('posts')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.data().title)
        console.log(doc.data().pid)
        posts.push({
          pid: doc.data().pid,
          title: doc.data().title,
        })
      })
      console.log(posts)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
    })

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```

When I `console.log(posts)` in `getStaticProps`, I can see the posts but somehow it is not display in the Home component.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the promise returned from `get()` to complete, thus returning an empty `posts` (you only fill that variable after the promise returrns, on the `then` part). In fact, if you put the `console.log(posts)` right before the return (instead of on the `then` part of the observable), you'll see it's empty there.

So you just need to `await` it... something like (obviously untested):

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    let posts = []
    try 
    {
      // await the promise
      const querySnapshot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .get();
    
      // "then" part after the await
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.data().title)
        console.log(doc.data().pid)
        posts.push({
          pid: doc.data().pid,
          title: doc.data().title,
        })
      })
      console.log(posts)
    } catch(error) {
        // catch part using try/catch
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
        // return something else here, or an empty props, or throw an exception or whatever 
    }

    return {
        props: {
          posts
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you fetch multiple collections and return them all together so a page with multiple child components, each needing different data, could get all the collections in a single props object?

Comment: @KirkRoss i guess it's been some months but the answer would proprably be "Promise.all"